# How do I push useRouter to a new url with Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js

I have a simple Searchbar component in Next.js that I'd like to keep in my main navbar and use on a search.js page.  I only need it to send the user to `/search?q=INPUTVALUE`, however, upon submitting, it always stays on the same page and merely appends `?q=INPUTVALUE`, ignoring the specified "/search".

For example, if submitted on my about.js page my url would be `/about?q=INPUTVALUE`.  It works as desired on search.js.

What am I missing?

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

const Searchbar = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
 
    const handleParam = setValue => e => setValue(e.target.value)
 
    const handleSubmit = () => {
      router.push({
        pathname: '/search',
        query: {q: query},
      })
    }
 
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='q'
          value={query}
          onChange={handleParam(setQuery)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
 }

export default Searchbar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Search is a form element, so without interruption, it will always redirect you back to the current page. Add `preventDefault()` should fix the problem here.

Q: Is there a reason to use a closure in your handleParam function? Wouldn't it work if you just do `const handleParam = e => setQuery(e.target.value)` and use it on your onchange `onChange={handleParam}`

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

const Searchbar = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
 
    const handleParam = setValue => e => setValue(e.target.value)
 
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      router.push({
        pathname: '/search',
        query: {q: query},
      })
    }
 
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='q'
          value={query}
          onChange={handleParam(setQuery)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
 }

export default Searchbar
```

Comment: Thank you very much Toxnyc, preventDefault() got this working.  This was driving me crazy, I appreciate it.  As for your other suggestion, removing the closure works just fine and cleans up the code quite a bit, thank you for that.  I'm still learning and this has been a big help!